# Table row display toggle does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, firefox, html-table

I have a Javascript function that works in IE7, but is giving me trouble in Firefox.

JAVASCRIPT

```
function vehicleSelected() {
   var ddlSelect = document.getElementById('ddlSelect');
   var displayTable = document.getElementsByName('listTable')[0];
   var strAuto = ddlSelect.options[ddlSelect.selectedIndex].value;
   alert("ok, so far");
   var rows = displayTable.getElementsByTagName("tr");
   alert("this alert is not triggered");
   var rowData = document.getElementById(strData);
   for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      rows[i].style.display = 'none';
   }
   rowData.style.display = '';
}
```

I am not sure how the rest of the code gets processed.  Is there a universal way to toggle the display for a table row or do I need one for Firefox separate?

**EDIT**

```
<table id="listTable">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your post leaves out a lot of details, but i'm guessing your html looks something like this

```
<table id='listTable' name='listTable'>
```

`name` is apparently not a valid attribute for a `table` (no mention [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp) and visual studio intellisense agrees), so firefox ignores that attribute and does not find any elements named `listTable`. `displayTable` is undefined in the firefox execution.

internet explorer however, with it's neverending insistence for doing things wrong, sees that the `id` attribute has a value of `'listTable'` and considers that good enough to qualify for `getElementsByName`. IE does not actually consider the `name` attribute you have given your table- it's just getting lucky. removing the `id` attribute will cause your method to fail in IE too.

Comment: That did help, but I am still stuck on how I would be able to call the table for use in the javascript.  I made edits to display the table in the html

Comment: replace `document.getElementsByName('listTable')[0];` with `document.getElementById('listTable');`. this is the preferred way to do this anyway.